# Alert message will show up after the submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My alert message pop ups before the loading/submission of a record, so if the user didn't input any data. It still pops up. What additional javascript function should I use for my alert box?

Here's my code

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("Adding Succesful!");
}
```

```html
<label for="bName" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Brand Name</p></label>
 <input name="bName" class="form-control req" required/> 

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default bt"  onclick="myFunction()" style="align:right;">ADD</button>
```

Comment: If you want to display the alert *after* something happens then you'd need to write the code in response to that event.  If the form is being submitted via AJAX then you'd display the alert in the response handler for the AJAX call.  If the form is being submitted at the browser level then you'd need to display the alert on the next page instead of this one.

Comment: Do you mean you need to stop submission of the form when form validation fails ? if so, add `return false;` to your `myFunction` when your form validation fails.

Comment: or atleast the "required/" must first shows up before the alert

Comment: @Sachin If there is any false validation the alert message will not pop up

Comment: You have only one input field?

Comment: @Sandeep No, I just shown one as an example

Comment: @Vista: I hope you are wrapping your input fields and the submit button inside a `form`?

Comment: Would you mind if I use `jquery validate` plugin for this?

Answer (score 3):

Use HTML5 validity checks to see if the form is valid or not.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('f');

function myFunction() {
  if (form.checkValidity()) {
    alert("Adding Succesful!");
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="f">
  <label for="bName" class="control-label col-xs-4">
    <p class="left">Brand Name</p>
  </label>
  <input name="bName" class="form-control req" required/>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default bt" onclick="myFunction()" style="align:right;">ADD</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The alert message doesn't pop up anymore? :(

Comment: It pops if it's valid.

Comment: You might not see the alert working because of the `sandbox` attribute that SO uses to show the snippet, but it works outside the `iframe` (this is just for demo purposes). Seems like Firefox doesn't care about the `sandbox` attribute as `allow-modals` is not set and it does show the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<label for="bName" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Brand Name</p></label>
 <input name="bName" class="form-control req" required/> 

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default bt"  onclick="return myFunction(this)" style="align:right;">ADD</button>
```

(note I changed the onclick to include a `return` and a `this`)

And use it with the JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(t)
{
    if($(t).prev().val())
    {
        alert('Adding Succesful!')
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```